# Loop in Gnu make file

Tags: shell, gnu, gnu-make

Can anyone please tell me the difference between for loop and foreach in makefiles? For example:

```
for fpga in $($(NE_NAME)_$(IS_DWDM)_FPGA); do\

$(foreach fpga, $($(NE_NAME)_$(DWDM_SUFFIX)_FPGA),ln -s $($(fpga)) $(PKG)/$(fpga);)
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the `for` loop is executed by the shell, but the `foreach` is executed by `make` while expanding the macro.  In the context shown, the shell executes the result of a `foreach`, but does not know there is a loop involved.